# Only first character of string is will print in C

Tags: c, data-structures, character-arrays

I have this struct

```
typedef struct grade
{
    char firstName[SIZE];
    char lastName[SIZE];
    int stuNum;
}GRADE;
```

and this output code:

```
void printData(GRADE grade[], int used)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<used-1; i++)
    {
        printf("%s %s %d\n", grade[i].firstName, grade[i].lastName, grade[i].stuNum);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to print the char's they only print the first character of the string, I'm at a stand still and cannot really figure out how to make it print the rest of the string.

This code reads the data file (which is in the format of `"Firstname Lastname StudentNumber"` in about 17 lines, for example `"Mark Markinson 1234"` `newline` `"blah blah 1234"` etc).

```
void readData(FILE *infile, GRADE grade[], int *count)
{
    char buf[SIZE] = {0};
    int position=*count;
    int used = 0;
    while( fgets(buf, SIZE, infile))
    { 
        removeNL(buf);

        grade[position].firstName[0] = parseName(buf, &used);
        used++;

        grade[position].lastName[0] = parseName(buf, &used);
        used++;

        grade[position].stuNum = parseNumber(buf, &used);
        used = 0;
        position++;
    }
    *count = position;

}
```

This is the code that parses the buffer for names:

```
char parseName(char *str, int *place)
{
    char buf[SIZE] = {0}, name;
    int i=*place,j=0;

    while( str[i] != '\0' && !isspace(str[i]))
    {
        buf[j++] = str[i++];

    }
    buf[j] = '\0';

    *place = i;

    return *buf;
}
```

after taking some suggestions here i changed some of the code, but it still does the same thing (only first character is printed)

used this way to call the function

```
parseName(buf, &used, grade[position].firstName);
```

and parseName is now

```
void parseName(char *str, int *place, char *firstName)
{
    char buf[SIZE] = {0}, name;
    int i=*place,j=0;    
    while( str[i] != '\0' && !isspace(str[i]))
    {
        buf[j++] = str[i++];

    }
    buf[j] = '\0';

    *place = i;

    *firstName = *buf;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code? I can't see anything wrong there. I imagine the problem could be in the function that assigns to the struct members.

Comment: thank you for looking, i just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
void readData(FILE *infile, GRADE grade[], int *count)
{
    char buf[SIZE] = {0};
    int position=*count;
    int used = 0;
    while( fgets(buf, SIZE, infile))
    { 
        removeNL(buf);

        grade[position].firstName[0] = parseName(buf, &used);
        used++;

        grade[position].lastName[0] = parseName(buf, &used);
        used++;

        grade[position].stuNum = parseNumber(buf, &used);
        used = 0;
        position++;
    }
    *count = position;

}
```

When you call parseName, you just set the first characters. You should pass your array (where you will write the string) to parseName:

```
void readData(FILE *infile, GRADE grade[], int *count)
{
    char buf[SIZE] = {0};
    int position=*count;
    int used = 0;
    while( fgets(buf, SIZE, infile))
    { 
        removeNL(buf);

        parseName(buf, &used, grade[position].firstName);
        used++;

        parseName(buf, &used, grade[position].lastName);
        used++;

        grade[position].stuNum = parseNumber(buf, &used);
        used = 0;
        position++;
    }
    *count = position;

}
```

Don't forget to change parseName adding a parameter and writing the result to it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is a lot more clear now. I am not 100% sure how I should add the parameter, I don't recall ever passing a structure element to a function like that before should make parseName "void parseName(char *str, int *place, GRADE grade[])"? when i do this i get warnings and im assuming its wrong

Comment: In my example it's assuming a char * (it is passing the array of char, which can be cast implicitly to a pointer of char). If you want to pass the structure, change the function to receive a GRADe *grade, then call like this: parseName(buf, &used, &grade[position]).

Comment: thank you for explaining further, it is appreiciated. i now did what was suggested and it does the same thing however. is it in the way i am printing?

Comment: looked in a debugger and firstName is only storing the first character. must be in how i am parsing

Comment: Figured it out, Chris Dodd's solution really helped a lot in addition to this solution

Answer (score 3):

`return *buf` returns (just) the first character in the buf, which is all that you are storing into the `firstName` and `lastName` arrays.  The problem is that arrays aren't first-class types in C, so you can't pass them as arguments to functions or return them as return values.

What you probably want to do is pass pointer to the buffer to fill in to `parseName` and have it fill it in rather than using a local buffer.  Then you just pass in `firstName` or `lastName` directly, which become pointers to the beginning of those fields.

Comment: I wish I could select more than one answer because without this I would still be stuck. thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In `parseName` you're putting all the input into the buffer and returning the first character, then assigning that character to `firstName[0]` or `lastName[0]` and never doing anything with the rest of the data that you put in the buffer. No wonder only one character is being printed.

You should probably change your

```
grade[position].firstName[0] = parseName(buf, &used);
```

to

```
parseName(grade[position].firstName, &used);
```

There's not really any reason to return the first character in `parseName`. You could change the return type of `parseName` to `char*` and return the `buf` instead of `*buf` for a little redundancy (some C functions do it) and that'd be better design.